# Problem in filling the slice of Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

My store code:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import contactSlice from "./contactSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    contact: contactSlice,
  },
});

export default store;
```

The code of my slice (namely contactSlice):

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const contactSlice = createSlice({
  name: "contact",
  initialState: {
  },
  reducers: {
    addContact: (state, action) => {
      state = { ...state, ...action.payload };
    },
    editContact: (state, action) => {
      state = { ...action.payload, ...state };
    },
    deleteContact: (action) => {
      delete action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { addContact } = contactSlice.actions;
export default contactSlice.reducer;
```

The code of my JSX which has three input fields namely firstName, LastName, and status, and the remaining react code where I have dispatched an action on clicking the submit button is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addContact } from "../utils/contactSlice";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState("Active");
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [LastName, setLastName] = useState("");

  console.log(isSelected, firstName, LastName);

  const contactDetails = {
    first: { firstName },
    last: { LastName },
    status: { isSelected },
  };
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const saveContact = () => {
    dispatch(addContact(contactDetails));
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col p-3 items-center">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold">Create Contact Screen</h2>
      <div className="w-full h-4/5 p-2 m-2 flex flex-col border-2 border-black">
        {/* first Name */}
        <div className="flex flex-row w-full justify-center"> 
          <span className="w-1/10 m-2 p-1 ">First Name :</span>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            className="w-[47%] m-2 p-1 border border-black focus:outline-none"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setFirstName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
        {/* Last name */}
        <div className="flex flex-row w-full justify-center">
          <span className="w-1/10 m-2 p-1 ">Last Name :</span>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            className="w-[47%] m-2 p-1 border border-black focus:outline-none"
            value={LastName}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setLastName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
        {/* status */}
        <div className="flex flex-row w-full justify-evenly">
          <div className="m-2 p-1 w-[23%]">Status :</div>
          <div className="flex flex-col ml-1 mr-28 px-1 items-center justify-evenly w-[14%]">
            <div className="flex flex-row">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="status"
                value="Active"
                checked={isSelected === "Active"}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setIsSelected(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              Active
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="status"
                value="Inactive"
                checked={isSelected === "Inactive"}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setIsSelected(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              Inactive
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        className="border border-black bg-blue-500 text-white m-5 p-2"
        onClick={() => saveContact()}
      >
        Save Contact
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

My app looks like :-
[image: This is Action tab of redux store on clicking the save contact button]

[image: This is State tab of the redux store on clicking the save contact button]

I am trying to store the input fields by putting them inside an object in my `contactSlice`.

I tried the above code... on clicking my save contact button my code should fill the contact slice with the `contactDetails` object that is present in my code.

What I think is that there is some issue in the `addContact()` of the `contactSlice` code.

Answer (score 1):

In Redux-Toolkit you should either mutate the existing state object ***or*** return the new state object (***never both!***), and ***never*** reassign the state. See [Direct State Mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation) for more details.

**Not OK**

```
someAction: (state, action) => {
  state = { .... } // reassigned to new object reference
}
```

**OK**

```
someAction: (state, action) => {
  state.property = action.payload.property;
}
```

```
someAction: (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    property: action.payload.property,
  };
}
```

Assuming the `contactSlice` state only holds the data for a single contact with `first`, `last`, and `status` properties I suggest the following:

```js
const initialState = {
  first: "",
  last: "",
  status: null,
};

const contactSlice = createSlice({
  name: "contact",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addContact: (state, action) => {
      const { first, last, status } = action.payload;
      state.first = first;
      state.last = last;
      state.status = status;

      // or return action.payload;
    },
    editContact: (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,          // shallow copy existing state first
        ...action.payload, // then shallow copy overwrites
      };
    },
    deleteContact: () => {
      return initialState; // reset to initial state
    }
  }
});
```

If the `contactSlice` is really supposed to hold an array of contacts then I suggest something similar to the following:

```js
import { createSlice, nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  contacts: []
};

const contactSlice = createSlice({
  name: "contact",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addContact: (state, action) => {
      state.contacts.push({
        id: nanoid(), // <-- GUID makes it trivial to identify contact
        ...action.payload,
      });
    },
    editContact: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action;

      const contact = state.contacts.find(
        contact => contact.id === payload.id
      );

      if (contact) {
        contact.first = action.payload.first;
        contact.last = action.payload.last;
        contact.status = action.payload.status;
      }
    },
    deleteContact: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action;

      state.contacts = state.contacts.filter(
        contact => contact.id !== payload.id
      );
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit problem-in-filling-the-slice-of-redux-store]

Comment: i changed my slice code  `const contactSlice = createSlice({
    name: "contact",
    initialState:{
        contacts : [],
    },
    reducers : {
        addContact : (state,action) =>{
            state.contacts.push(action.payload);
        },
        editContact : (state,action) =>{
            state = {...action.payload,...state};
        },
        deleteContact : (action) =>{
             delete action.payload;
        }
    }
});`     the addContact() reducer function is working , but I am not sure of the other two reducers @DrewReese

Comment: @akshatnigam I see, and that's not a problem at all. I've updated my answer to reflect a contacts array, and added a running sandbox demo.